# Masterpage and default page

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, master-pages

I would like my default.aspx to use masterpage but have a different body than the rest of my webpages is this possible? Basically I want my default.aspx to have a background image for the entire page but still use the masterpage because I have menu and things I would like to use on that page as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the styles and everything for a particular page in Content Page and not Master Page. In your case, if you want a separate styles and background for default.aspx, you can define those styles in default.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

inside of default.aspx do

```
<style>
BODY { background-image: url(....image here ....);}
</style>
```

I know it is not the nicest pattern but... cmon, masterpages

Answer (score 0):

You can inline it on default.aspx

```
<style>
    body{
        /*Background stuff here */
    }
</style>
```

or have an if on your master page

```
@if(currentpage == "home")
   <div id="background">

   </div>
@endif
```

or

```
@if(currentpage == "home")
   <body style="background-stuff-here">
@else
   <body>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in you master page head section

```
<head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/common1.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/common1.js"></script>
   <asp:contentplaceholder id="ExtraStylesAndScripts" runat="server" />
</head>
```

And these lines to you default page

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="ExtraStylesAndScripts" runat="server">    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/extra1.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/extra2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/extra1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/extra2.js"></script>
</asp:content>
```

Now you are free to set different page style for different content pages. 
You can change background or other appearance in "styles/extra1.css" files.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be a MultiView and pass in something like an enum object telling the master page what View to display. If you in the future need to add a different design for another page you can just add a View.